# How to close twitter stream

Tags: python, twitter, python-2.7, tweepy

I have included code below that I'm using with Tweepy, a Twitter API library for Python. While I'm trying most approaches that I've found online, they've failed to close the connection or stop the stream. Is there any way to do so?

Inside my function

```
 setTerms = s.split(',')
 streaming_api = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=StreamListener(), timeout=60 )
    if (s == '0'):
        streaming_api.disconnect()
        raise web.seeother('/dc')
        print "Failed to see this"
    try:
        twt = streaming_api.filter(track=setTerms)
    except:
        streaming_api.disconnect()
        #also cannot see this
    raise web.seeother('/stream')
```

Here is the stream listener class

```
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
        def on_status(self, status):
            try:
                printer(status.text, status.created_at)
            except Exception, e:
                pass
        def on_error(self, status_code): 
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
            return True
        def on_timeout(self): 
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
            return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you call `stream.disconnect()` (inside `if (s == '0'):`), you haven't called `filter` yet, so the stream will never be connected. The rest of your code should be correct, assuming you're using the latest version of `tweepy`. Note that the `except` block will almost never be called, as any errors that occur while the stream is running are passed to the `on_error` callback.